# Pagefactory dynamic webelement with wildcard

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, page-factory

I have dynamically generated locators depends on which element is gonna be chosen from a list.

For instance, this is my generated id:

```
Function:TableName:0:submenuAction
```

0 is the counter, meaning first element is chosen from the list. All strings before and after the counter won't change, so start with, contains xpath method does not work.

Can I use some wildcard like
   `Function:TableName:{X}:submenuAction` {x} is integer.

I can store the chosen number of element, but how can I use this variable inside the pagefactory element? driver.findelement can fail with staleElementException,thats why I wanna use PageFactory.

Comment: usually stale element error occurs when you try to access any element after changing the DOM state of the page. so if you want to use any element, you should get the reference instantly and then you can perform any action. for your better understanding of the scenario im writing some pseudo for triggering the stale element error.
1. get the reference of any element on the page (driver.findelement(....))
2. refresh page (driver.manage.navigate.refresh())
3. try to click on that element now (element.click())--> you will encounter stale element error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you're passing in would probably have to be a constant (e.g. `final static` in Java) to be used in a `PageFactory` annotation.

```
private final static int ITEM_INDEX = 2;

...

@FindBy(xpath="Function:TableName:"+ ITEM_INDEX + ":submenuAction")
private WebElement targetListItem;
```

In addition to some of the stale checking strategies mentioned in the comment, you may also want to try binding all of those dynamically-identified elements to a collection (e.g. `List<WebElement>`), then indexing in:

```
@FindBy(xpath="...")
private List<WebElement> allListEntries;

...

private WebElement getTargetListEntry(int index) {
    return allListEntries.get(index);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that, it have to be a constant. I do not know the index value just after a for loop. As far as I know, constant cannot be modified or initialized in such way. Any idea?

Comment: Ah, yeah. If you calculate the desired index dynamically, then the second example (grabbing all the items in that dynamic list and indexing in) is probably what you'll need to do.